# How can I find the language of this code and how can I find the tool to convert this code to text or HTML

Tags: html, hex, decimal

This is a code view of a text (html) But I can't find this language, I don't have any experience in coding, please help me.

```
&#1112&#965&#1109t
```

Comment: That is html.  What more do you want?

Comment: 'Please help' you do what?

Comment: Those are [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references). Placing them in an HTML document and then viewing the document in a browser should show you what they evaluate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to be HTML entities, but they are not complete, they should end with ';' So the code should read: &#1112;&#965;&#1109;t

The characters you see are:

```
&amp;#1112;   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER JE 
&amp;#965;    GREEK SMALL YPSILON 
&amp;#1109;   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DZE 
t             a normal t
```

In your browser it look almost like 'just'

For a chasrt of unicode characters: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but I wanna convert "just" to that code not convert that code to text (just).I can't find any converter,please help

Comment: You are not very clear, first of all what language are you programming in? And second why do you want to convert to these codes? Wouldn't it be better to set the character encoding of your HTML to Unicode or UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

your text translates to "јυѕt;"